# Add EditText to hash map android

Tags: java, android, hash

Hi I am just looking for some advice on how to approach adding 2 seperate edittext values to a hash map.

Basically, I have the name of an item in one edittext, and the price of the item in the next one.
I want to click add and for both values to be stored together.

My aim is to add these details to a spinner and when its selected I can show the value that is associated with it.

I am just looking for some direction if that is possible, I am able to add one hash map entry to a spinner but I am having trouble adding two connected values at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not creating a new class Item in which you put the two attributes the name of the item and it price, and then create a hash map of this class.
Your class should look like this:

```
public class Item{
private String itemName;
private String itemPrice;//or put an integer instead.
public Item (String n, String p){
this.itemName = n;
this.itemPrice =p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText itemNameInput, itemPriceInput;

HashMap<Integer, String> inputMap = new HashMap<>();

public void onAddClicked() {
  String itemName = itemNameInput.getText().toString();
  String itemPrice = itemPriceInput.getText().toString();

  inputMap.put(itemNameInput.getId(), itemName);
  inputMap.put(itemPriceInput.getId(), itemPrice);

  // iterate over hashmap -> arrayadapter backing spinner
}
```

But why do you need a hashmap? You want to be able to lookup the EditTexts after the spinner is clicked? You're probably better off just concatenating the name and price (`String spinnerItemOne = itemName + " " + itemPrice;`) then feeding that to your spinner's array adapter. You can use the hashmap if you need, for instance, to send focus back to the itemNameInput. I just used the id since I don't know more about what you're trying to do: you can use the actual edit texts as keys as well (just don't leak them). On a final note, that it matters to much if you are only doing this pair, but you might use a `SparseArray` instead of the hashmap for more efficiency.

Comment: Anix Pasbesoin's suggestion is a good one, particularly to feed the adapter backing the spinner.